# Changing the URL when loading Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dynamic

So what I'm trying to do is changing the content of a div through javascript, that also changes the URL in the browser.

What I have in my `index.php` is something like this:

```
<a href="#page" onclick="loadContent()";>
<div id="pageContent"> 
        Here is some content
</div>
```

In my .js-file I have a function like this to replace the content in the `div`:

```
function loadContent()
{
     $("#pageContent").load("new_page.php");
}
```

What happens now is that the URL in the browser changes to something like this: `exmaple.com/#page` . But when I reload this link afterwards it loads the "old content" of the page and not the site with the changed div.

How is it possible to load the new content AND change the URL in a way, that after I'm typing `exmaple.com/#page` in the URL, it loads the page with the new content in the div?

Comment: if you want to load content based on hash you need to parse the hash and pass to your loading logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either:

1) ditch the ajax and just use a normal link

2) check the hash value on pageload, and then load in the correct content:

```
$(function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    var pages = ['home','contact','about'];
    if(pages.indexOf(hash) > 0){
        $("#pageContent").load(hash+".php");
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! Checking the hash-value was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Use window.location = "/absolute/path/to/page#your-div-id";**

You can use `.scrollIntoView()` on the targeted page element.

`document.getElementById("the_div_id").scrollIntoView(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a onLoad-method to check if you need to load any page content.

```
<body onload="onPageLoad();">

function onPageLoad() {
  var location = window.location.hash;
  if(location == "somePage") {
    loadContent();
  }
}
```

If you are using JQuery, you can also use the Ready-Event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /** code **/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event listener to check when the anchor changes and check when the page load for any anchor.

```
//Listener
$(window).on('hashchange', loadPage);
$(window).on('load', loadPage);

function loadPage() {
   if(loaction.hash.length > 1) {
      //The anchor has been changed.
      loadContent("example.com/example.php?page=" + location.hash.substring(1));
   } else {
      //Load standard page if no anchor
      ...
   }

}
```

The script load a page when the anchor changes.

```
<a href="#page">Page</a>
```